# How to use a 2D array as a result from a function in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sh, regex-group

I have the following function:

```
function regex_match_2d_list {
  local regex=$1
  local text=$2
  local groups=()
  while [[ $text =~ $regex ]]; do
    local group=()
    for (( i=0; i<${#BASH_REMATCH[@]}; i++ )); do
      group+=("${BASH_REMATCH[$i]}")
    done
    groups+=("${group[@]}")
    text=${text#*"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"}
  done
  echo "${groups[@]}"
}
```

what I am trying to do is to have a function that is going to receive a regex and a text and it will output a 2d list where each element of that list is composed of all the groups from regex:

```py
pattern="^([a-z]+)\s([a-z]+)"
text="hello world
foo bar"

res=$(regex_match_2d_list "$pattern" "$text")
echo "${res[0,1]}"
```

if I did understand it correctly, by doing res[0,2] I should receive "world" because is the second group of the first element.
[image]

but instead if am not getting anything. Could anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: you can debug those problem yourself by adding 'declare -p BASH_REMATCH text` immediately after the match. Short version below:

The line: `text=${text#*"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"}` is expected to remove the match. However, the match does NOT include the trailing separators after the second token (new line between "hello world" and "foo bar"). You want to change the match to remove any trailing new line.

One possible solution - add the new line to the end of the pattern. To handle the last line which is not terminated with new line - I made it optional (with '?'). Possible to append new line to the text as alternative.

```
pattern="^([a-z]+)\s([a-z]+)"$'\n?'
```

Second issue is the transfer of BASH_REMATCH to groups (via intermediate group variable). Current code also copy element 0 of RE_BATCH, which will result in duplicating entries in groups. Consider using `groups+=(${BASH_REMATCH[@]}` instead.

Last problem is the assignment to 'res'. Current code will 'flatten' the array into single string. You probably want to get res as an array. One possible (but not always safe) to use array assignment res=($(regex_match ...)).

Final code:

```
function regex_2 {
  local regex=$1
  local text=$2
  local groups=()
  while [[ $text =~ $regex ]]; do
    groups+=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}")
    text=${text#*"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"}
  done
  echo "${groups[@]}"
}

pattern="^([a-z]+)\s([a-z]+)"$'\n?'
text="hello world
foo bar"

res=($(regex_2 "$pattern" "$text"))
declare -p res
```

Comment: that's almost ok, but if I am running you code I will have each element twice. 
declare -a res=([0]="hello" [1]="world" [2]="hello" [3]="world" [4]="foo" [5]="bar" [6]="foo" [7]="bar")
Any idea why?

Comment: Oops, I did not notice. I've updated: `groups+=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}")` so it will not copy the first element which include the complete matched text

Comment: even if your function runs ok for this example I think something is wrong, or is it not suppose to work with any regex?

For example by using this regex: `$'\[OK\][[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]_]+)\.([[:alnum:]_]+)([^[]*)'`

and the fallowing text: 
`org_output="[OK] AAA.BBBBBB
aaabbbcccdddfffed
asdadadadadadsada
[OK] CCC.KKKKKKK
some text here
[OK] OKO.II"`

Comment: the output from your function will be: `declare -a res=([0]="[OK]" [1]="AAA.BBBBBB" [2]="aaabbbcccdddfffed" [3]="asdadadadadadsada" [4]="AAA" [5]="BBBBBB" [6]="aaabbbcccdddfffed" [7]="asdadadadadadsada" [8]="[OK]" [9]="CCC.KKKKKKK" [10]="some" [11]="text" [12]="here" [13]="CCC" [14]="KKKKKKK" [15]="some" [16]="text" [17]="here" [18]="[OK]" [19]="OKO.II" [20]="OKO" [21]="II" [22]="AAA" [23]="BBBBBB" [24]="aaabbbcccdddfffed" [25]="asdadadadadadsada" [26]="CCC" [27]="KKKKKKK" [28]="some" [29]="text" [30]="here" [31]="OKO" [32]="II")
`

Comment: but if I will do it via while: `while [[ $org_output =~ $regex_pattern_run ]]; do
  declare -p BASH_REMATCH
  org_output=${org_output#*"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"}
done` it is going to be `declare -a BASH_REMATCH=([0]=$'[OK] AAA.BBBBBB\naaabbbcccdddfffed\nasdadadadadadsada\n' [1]="AAA" [2]="BBBBBB" [3]=$'\naaabbbcccdddfffed\nasdadadadadadsada\n')
declare -a BASH_REMATCH=([0]=$'[OK] CCC.KKKKKKK\nsome text here\n' [1]="CCC" [2]="KKKKKKK" [3]=$'\nsome text here\n')
declare -a BASH_REMATCH=([0]="[OK] OKO.II" [1]="OKO" [2]="II" [3]="")
`

Comment: isn't it suppose to get the same answer? Or I did get it wrong?

Comment: @Mircea: I execute the example with '[OK] AAA.BBBB ...', I'm getting:
declare -a res=([0]="AAA" [1]="BBBBBB" [2]="aaabbbcccdddfffed" [3]="asdadadadadadsada" [4]="CCC" [5]="KKKKKKK" [6]="some" [7]="text" [8]="here" [9]="OKO" [10]="II")
Which I believe is the expected output. I'm using Ubunto on WIN10 (bash 5.0). I'm not sure how do you get the output your described (with [OK]). Do you have any leftover 'echo' in your function ?

Comment: Well I am sure then that I am getting it right but based on that regex that I gave it to you I would expect this outpus: `declare -a BASH_REMATCH=([0]=$'[OK] AAA.BBBBBB\naaabbbcccdddfffed\nasdadadadadadsada\n' [1]="AAA" [2]="BBBBBB" [3]=$'\naaabbbcccdddfffed\nasdadadadadadsada\n')
declare -a BASH_REMATCH=([0]=$'[OK] CCC.KKKKKKK\nsome text here\n' [1]="CCC" [2]="KKKKKKK" [3]=$'\nsome text here\n')
declare -a BASH_REMATCH=([0]="[OK] OKO.II" [1]="OKO" [2]="II" [3]="")
`

Comment: If you copy my regex and my text example and then go try them over here https://regex101.com/ it would display the same result. I am not sure why that function is not working in the same way, or I did not really understand the solution.

Comment: or to put it simply... why there is a difference between your function and this code:  `while [[ $org_output =~ $regex_pattern_run ]]; do
  declare -p BASH_REMATCH
  org_output=${org_output#*"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"}
done` isn't it supposed to do the exact same thing?

Comment: more then that, I've just tested, I've I will run the exact same code that is inside that function: `var_test=()
while [[ $org_output =~ $regex_pattern_run ]]; do
  var_test+=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}")
  org_output=${org_output#*"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"}
done

declare -p var_test` I will get the expected output: `declare -a var_test=([0]="AAA" [1]="BBBBBB" [2]=$'\naaabbbcccdddfffed\nasdadadadadadsada\n' [3]="CCC" [4]="KKKKKKK" [5]=$'\nsome text here\n' [6]="OKO" [7]="II" [8]="")
`
but somehow this is not working within the function...

Comment: I did ask a new question, if you would be kind to help me also whit this one, I've explained everything over there :).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74946104/why-dose-not-echo-return-the-same-thing-as-without

Comment: @Mircea I've posted an answer to the other question that cover the case where the text contain non alphanumeric characters.